# Вывод записей из БД по дате за каждый день и за период в неделю

Tags: дата, mysql

Всем привет.

Никак не могу понять и найти решения как сделать.

Имеем таблицу 
news (
  news_id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  news_added datetime NOT NULL,
  news_title varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (news_id),
  KEY idx_news_added (news_added)
)

Суть в том, чтобы вывести новости, например за неделю по дням.
Т.е.

> 27.11.2012 Новость 4572 | Новость 4571 | Новость 4570
>
> 26.11.2012 Новость 4569
>
> 25.11.2012 Новость 4568 | Новость 4567

Одним запросом такое возможно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сначала
SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `news_added` DESC

потом на php

```
$news = array();
while ($item = ...->fetch_assoc()){
    $news[$item['news_added']][] = $items['news_title '];
}
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Я уже сделал так же. Допер, что сложного ничего и нет в итоге то)

Answer (score 3):

Сымпровизировал немного Ваш запрос у себя в базе

```
-- Структура таблицы `tete`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tete` (
  `news_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `news_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `news_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`news_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп дадзеных табліцы `tete`
--

INSERT INTO `tete` (`news_id`, `news_added`, `news_title`) VALUES
(1, '2012-11-01 05:17:24', 'new 4000'),
(2, '2012-11-01 05:17:24', 'New 4001'),
(3, '2012-11-01 05:17:24', 'new 40011'),
(4, '2012-11-02 05:17:25', 'New 4002'),
(5, '2012-11-02 05:17:25', 'New 4003');
```

Сам запрос

```
SELECT `news_added` , GROUP_CONCAT( `news_title` ) AS `news_title` 
FROM `tete`
GROUP BY `news_added`
```

Результат

```
news_added  news_title
2012-11-01 05:17:24     new 4000,New 4001,new 40011
2012-11-02 05:17:25     New 4002,New 4003
```

Comment: Еслі за неделю, то добавте после FROM что-то такое

WHERE
(`news_added` > '2012-11-01 00:00:00') AND
(`news_added` < '2012-11-07 00:00:00')

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT не то как я понял.
Мне нужно вывести типа дерева и получить массив, чтобы передать его в шаблон используя smarty.

Это как вывод карты сайта, когда по месяцам построен вывод.
В моем случае не месяц, а неделя является пределом.

Comment: наверное либо подзапрос делать на выборку записей в зависимости от текущий даты, либо можно как-то одним. либо рекурсивно сливать как-то в нужный массив.
я просто никогда не сталкивался, по этому не знаю как такое делается правильно.

Comment: SELECT выводит Вам таблицу данных, а дальше надо работать уже с ней. Выбирайте через массив из неё данные и записывайте в smarty
Вывести как дерево, то, если не ошибаюсь тут уже не mysql, а css + html + php.

Извиняйте, если что-нибудь не так понял.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/10443/dropoff "Мне нужно вывести типа дерева и получить массив". Об этом речь не велась в вашем вопросе.
У вас есть пример, по нему вам был сделан ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Гугланул по вашему вопросу нашел `GROUP_CONCAT`
Время из даты сами уберете, если оно там записывается.
Ну и `WHERE` подпишите.

```
SELECT news_added, GROUP_CONCAT(news_title) FROM News
GROUP BY news_added
```